# Who can i append a prefix and a suffix to the URL's generated by grunt-wiredep?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, grunt-wiredep

I am trying to utilize grunt-wiredep to alter my source-code in a spring-boot project.

Using bower works as expected by pulling down the JS/CSS and the dependencies, and grunt-wiredep will update the sourcecode, but i need to surround the URL with @{URL_GOES_HERE} due to the way i utilize thymeleaf.

Is this possible? Does grunt-wiredep have a prefix/suffix option? (I have not found this so far).

**Current output**:

```
<!-- bower-js:start -->
    <script src="bower_components\bootstrap-colorpicker\js\bootstrap-colorpicker.js">
    </script>
<!-- bower-js:end -->
```

**Desired output:**

```
<!-- bower-js:start -->
    <script src="@{\bower_components\bootstrap-colorpicker\js\bootstrap-colorpicker.js}">
    </script>
<!-- bower-js:end -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grunt-wiredep` can utilize any configuration option provided by the [original `wiredep`](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#configuration).

On the above link you can see that the output format can be configured too, the github readme gives an example of appending a random class to the script tag:

```
fileTypes: {
fileExtension: {
  block: /match the beginning-to-end of a bower block in this type of file/,
  detect: {
    typeOfBowerFile: /match the way this type of file is included/
  },
  replace: {
    typeOfBowerFile: '<format for this {{filePath}} to be injected>',
    anotherTypeOfBowerFile: function (filePath) {
      return '<script class="random-' + Math.random() + '" src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
    }
  }
}, //...
```

So for example, you can override the default HTML fileExtension config block like this:

```
html: {
  block: /(([ \t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi,
  detect: {
    js: /<script.*src=['"]([^'"]+)/gi
  },
  replace: {
    js: '<script src="@{\\{{filePath}}}"></script>'
  }
},
```